# Variables in Rename function

Tags: c, rename, codeblocks

I use Code::Blocks and I want to create a program for personal use, but I have a problem, this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int number;
    char name[100];
    char extension[100];
    int I;

    printf("Filename: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    system("CLS");
    printf("File number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    system("CLS");
    printf("Extension: ");
    scanf("%s", extension);
    system("CLS");
    for ((I = 1); (I = number); (I++))
    {
        rename(("&s-%d%s"), ("%s-%d.tmp1"), name, number, extension); //ERROR HERE
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when I compile, I get an error:

```
error: too many arguments to function 'rename'
```

thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: I think you are looking for the [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the `rename()` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename), The `rename()` function has only 2 input arguments `oldpath` and `newpath`

```
int rename(const char *oldpath, const char *newpath);
```

So you can add this before calling the `rename()` function in your code

```
char oldpath[200], newpath[200];
sprintf(oldpath, "%s-%d%s", name, number, extension);
sprintf(newpath, "%s-%d.tmp1", name, number);

rename(oldpath, newpath);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a simple method.

Answer (score 3):

`rename` only takes 2 arguments and you're passing 4.

```
NAME
     rename -- change the name of a file

SYNOPSIS
     #include <stdio.h>

     int
     rename(const char *old, const char *new);
```

You probably want to use `sprintf()` prior to your call to `rename` based on your code.

Additionally, you probably want a <= here for this to work as you expect:

```
for ((I = 1); (I <= number); (I++))
```

Answer (score 2):

`rename()` is not a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), meaning you can't pass it as many variables as you want.

If you want to use [`rename(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename) or [`rename(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rename) you need to only use 2 strings. So if you want to use variable names, combine the strings together then pass 2 variables to the function.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rename/

He is the reference.  You do have too many arguments.  It only takes two char arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here isn't in your code. Which book are you reading?

How many arguments does [this manual](http://www.opengroup.org/susv3xsh/rename.html) say `rename` accepts? Is there anything there that indicates that `rename` uses [printf-like format strings](http://www.opengroup.org/susv3xsh/fprintf.html)? No?

That's the problem when you assume you can learn by trial and error, without reading any manuals. C is dangerous to learn like that. If your programs end up using undefined behaviour, they *might work* on your machine *sometimes*, and fail for mysterious reasons and in mysterious ways, fail to work entirely on other machines, etc. Do yourself a favour and quit the guessing; Get a book, if you haven't already got one, and read it! You'll end up learning to write portable code far quicker than guessing/trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Try learning how to use ellipsis operator as given in K&R....implementation of printf function 
.